# How do you fetch a position based on a criteria match using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML:

```
<summary>
<test>
   <name>test1</name>
   <status>failure</status>
</test>
<test>
   <name>test2</name>
   <status>success</status>
</test>
<test>
   <name>test3</name>
   <status>success</status>
</test>
</summary>
```

If <status> is success, I need to store the position() of <test> node in a variable and fetch it from the next template. I only need the position() of the first match. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I recommend to use a global variable that holds the wanted position**:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vFirstPassedPosition" select=
     "count(/*/test
                [status='success'][1]
                   /preceding-sibling::test) +1"/>
```

Because this variable is global (child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`), it can be referenced from any template without the need for recalculation within the template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFirstPassedPosition" select=
 "count(/*/test
           [status='success'][1]
                  /preceding-sibling::test) +1"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vFirstPassedPosition"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this sample transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<summary>
    <test>
        <name>test1</name>
        <status>failure</status>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>test2</name>
        <status>success</status>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>test3</name>
        <status>success</status>
    </test>
</summary>
```

**the position is accessed from within any template (in this case we have a single template) and output correctly**:

```
2
```

**In case if the XML document's structure is unknown/unpredictable, and can have any level of nesting**, including nested `test` elements, then use:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vFirstPassedPosition" select=
  "count((//test[status='success'])[1]
                  /preceding::test)
  +
   count((//test[status='success'])[1]
                  /ancestor::test)

   +1"/>
```

**Do note**: It is wrong to use expressions like the following in order to find the first `test` element the string value of whose `status` child is `"success"`:

```
//test[status='success'][1]
```

1. In your case the `//` pseudo-operator isn't necessary at all, as the structure of the XML document is statically known and more efficient XPath expressions can be used.
2. `//test[status='success'][1]` in general may select more than one element. It selects any `test` element the string value of whose `status` child is `"success"` and which is the first child of its parent. This is one of the most FAQ in XPath. **Remember**: The XPath `[]` operator has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator. In case you really *must* use `//` (for example the exact structure of the XML document is not known in advance), then the proper XPath to select the first such element is:

:

```
(//test[status='success'])[1]
```

As in many other programming languages (and generally in mathematics) brackets are used to explicitly override the standard operators' precedence.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to store the position() of  node in a variable and fetch
>   it from the next template.

"The next template" doesn't mean anything in XSLT. Templates are not specified to be executed in a particular order. XSLT is declarative rather than procedural. Maybe you mean the template that is applied to the following `<test>` element.

Because of this unspecified order of application of templates, it doesn't make sense to store something during the application of one template, and retrieve it during the application of another, because you may end up trying to retrieve it before you store it.

The solution, when thinking from a declarative point of view, is:

- If the template being applied to element X needs data about element Y than is *not* dependent on the current context, just use a global variable and compute the data once. This is the case you're looking at (since you only need the first test that passed), and this is the case @Dimitre has given you the answer for.
- If the template being applied to element X needs data about element Y than *is*  dependent on the current context, compute the value within the template that needs it (the template processing element X), rather than in the template that processes element Y.